# Delphi XE5: DBEdit background color not working if Field is numeric and application has not default style

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, vcl-styles

I'm not able to change `DBEdit` background color at runtime.
If `DbEdit` `styleElements` are enabled (`[seFont,seClient,seBorder]`) `DBEditName.Color:=clRed` (for example) **not working at all**. Instead if `styleElements=[]` `DBEditName.Color:=clRed` changes **only the `DBEdit` border** (see image below).  but I'd like a full background color. How can i achieve that?

**EDIT**

The problem arises when DBEdit Datasource Field is NUMERIC (content is aligned right) and Application has a not-default style applied (no Windows style)

[image]

Comment: Could you include your Delphi version tag into your question ? I cannot reproduce what you described in Delphi XE3. Btw. if you keep included all the style elements, the control is styled by the selected style, so it's correct that you can't change the color. You'd need to exclude the `seClient` element. But then it works as expected (in Delphi XE3).

Comment: sorry, you're right! I'm using XE5

Comment: with styleElements=[] only the border is painted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, hope it helps.

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object DBEdit1: TDBEdit
    Left = 72
    Top = 72
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    StyleElements = [seFont, seBorder]
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 144
    Top = 136
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

PAS:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBEdit1.Color := clred;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please look at the EDIT lines in my question. I have defined the problem better